# Rails 4 routing excluding :new action breaks rspec routing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, url-routing

I have a simple controller that is supposed to respond to just show and index actions. In order to tighten up my routes, I have added the condition to only handle :show and :index. The problem is that this appears to force the show action to respond to pro_infos/new, where it presumably sees 'new' as the :id param.

Not a real problem in itself, but it breaks my rspec routing test for new to not be routable.

**From routes:**

```
resources :masters, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
    resources :pro_infos, only: [:show, :index]    
end
```

**From rspec routing**

```
it "routes to #new" do
  expect(:get => "masters/2/pro_infos/new").not_to be_routable
end
```

`rake routes |grep pro_infos` returns:

```
master_pro_infos GET    /masters/:master_id/pro_infos(.:format)                                                  pro_infos#index
master_pro_info GET    /masters/:master_id/pro_infos/:id(.:format)                                              pro_infos#show
```

I understand that I can just cut out the routing test for the new action, but for the sake of consistency across my application I would prefer to test for the routing not responding to it. What is the correct / best-practice approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a constraint (seen [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)) to your route to only allow integer IDs like this:

```
resources :masters, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
  resources :pro_infos, only: [:show, :index], constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
end
```

Comment: What if using vanity URLs, i.e. `/masters/1/pro_infos/vanity-url`, where you could have alphabetical characters passed through as the `id` value?